Two database Transaction with same database variable
the code looks like this..
private var db = Firebase.firestore

db.collection("Classes").document("ClassID").get(resource)
                .addOnSuccessListener {  
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                }
db.collection("Teacher").document("TeacherID").set(resource2)
                .addOnSuccessListener {  
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                }
db.collection("Students").document("StudentID").get(resource3)
                .addOnSuccessListener {  
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                }

I'm using different database variable for each transaction. But to reduce the coding, is this okay to use, or does it mess the whole database transaction?

There is no database transaction in the code you shared. Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#kotlin+ktx?

Maybe transaction is not the good term.. I'm not fluent in English, i mean, can i use the same variable all over again with reading and writing to the database?.

Yes, you can use the same db to access the database multiple times.
